# Why is the compiler rejecting an explicit specialization for a const pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization, const-reference

Consider the following program:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(const T& x);

template <>
char const * foo<char const *>(char const *& x);
```

where I'm just using specializing `const char*`. The compiler won't accept this! It [tells me](https://godbolt.org/z/E1EeMjqch) (GodBolt.org):

```
<source>:5:14: error: template-id 'foo<const char*>' for 'const char* foo(const char*&)' does not match any template declaration
    5 | char const * foo<char const *>(char const *& x)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:3: note: candidate is: 'template<class T> T foo(const T&)'
    2 | T foo(const T& x);
      |   ^~~
```

Why isn't it accepting my specialization? Am I misunderstanding how template specialization works?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of templates is fine, but you're getting confused by C++ type syntax, and by a finer point of reference semantics.

You see, your specializing function needs to take a `const T&`, for `T` being `char const *`. You wrote `const char*&` - but in this type, it is only the pointed-to data that is `const`, while the reference is non-const.

Now, you might ask, "What do you mean, the reference is non-const? It's a reference, it can't change; and I can't change anything using the pointer, since it points to const data!" ... well, you're mostly right, but - you can *assign* to a non-const reference to a pointer, can't you? And that will change the pointer variable's value at the call site.

What you need to write is:

```
template <>
char const * foo<char const *>(char const * const & x);
```

i.e. with a rather-redundant extra `const` indicator, applying to the reference rather than the character data. This will [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/P8a31KeMG) (GodBolt.org).